# Google Apps script. For loop is not working

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried to write an Apps script for sending emails for those who forgot to update status report using google form.
It's my 1st script and I tried to fix it for almost 5 hours unsuccessfully.

Here is code:

```
function sendEmails() {
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("summary");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

    for ( var i=2; i<=lastRow; i++){

      var currentEmail = sheet.getRange(i,11).getValue();
      var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("emailbody").getRange(1,1).getValue();
      var emailRecipient = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",emailRecipient);

      var oldCheck = sheet.getRange(i,12).getValue();

      if (oldCheck = "Old"){
      MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,"Reminder: Fill the weekly status update form",messageBody); 
      } 
      else {
        continue;
      }

    }
  
}
```

It sends only 1 email for the first "old" check.

Comment: First of, the `continue;` will actually exit the for-loop whenever it finds the first e-mail that isn't old. Second, the if-statement should be like this: `if (oldCheck === "Old") {`. `==` checks for value equality only. It inherently does type coercion. This means that before checking the values, it converts the types of the variables to match each other.
On the other hand, `===` does not perform type coercion. It will verify whether the variables being compared have both the same value AND the same type.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

**Issue:**

You want to **compare** the value of `oldCheck` with "Old" and not **assign** "Old" to `oldCheck`. You need to use `==` instead of `=`.

**Improvements:**

It is computationally expensive to use `getValue` inside a for loop. Instead use `getValues` before the for loop and work with the arrays. In this way, you eliminate reduntant API calls that make your script heavy especially when `i` increases.

### Solution:

```
function sendEmails() {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("summary");
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var templateText = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("emailbody").getRange(1,1).getValue();
    for (var i=1; i<data.length; i++){    
      var currentEmail = data[i][12];
      var emailRecipient = data[i][3];
      var messageBody = templateText.replace("{name}",emailRecipient);
      var oldCheck = data[i][13];  
      // be careful! == instead of =
      if (oldCheck == "Old"){
        MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail,"Reminder: Fill the weekly status update form",messageBody); 
        } 
        else {
          continue;
        }
    }
}
```